# using string in an IN clause

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

```
    UPDATE assets a 
SET a.labor_c_start_dt = '2017-01-01',
a.labor_c_end_dt = '2017-12-31'

WHERE a.asset = IN(asset1,asset2,asset3)
```

I'm trying to get it to check for the asset name match it and then adjust the following fields. but for some reason, it will not function.

Please help?

Thanks

Comment: please remove '=' after 

Where a.asset

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose the strings into quotes, e.g.:

```
UPDATE assets a 
SET a.labor_c_start_dt = '2017-01-01',
a.labor_c_end_dt = '2017-12-31'
WHERE a.asset IN('asset1','asset2','asset3')
```

Comment: i get an Error Code: 1064 when added inclosed in quotes

Comment: Sorry, removed a typo in answer (`=`) can you try now?